# Linq to SQL Server - difficulty with sub-query example

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a SQL Server table that contains the following fields:

- SessionId (guid)
- Message (varchar)
- Timestamp (datetime)

What I need to do is to pull out the FIRST record for EACH SessionId using LINQ to SQL (ideally as a lambda, but query syntax would be useful)

It's relatively simple to do this with t-SQL....

```
SELECT al.Message, al.SessionId, al.Timestamp
FROM AppLog AS al
WHERE al.Timestamp = 
(select MIN(al2.Timestamp) from ApplicationLog as al2 where al2.SessionId = al.SessionId)
```

I've tried to do the same with a Lambda query (using joins) but it's just not working...

Any/all help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Griff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I'm being simplistic-- but if this is one table, then this should work?

```
db.Applog.GroupBy(a=>a.SessionID).Select(g=>g.OrderBy(m=>m.Timestamp).First());
```

Comment: Although Frank's answer was perfectly correct, this seems more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You tried using linquer?
http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Query syntax might look a bit nicer than a lambda -

```
var x = from al in db.AppLog
where al.Timestamp == 
  (from al2 in db.ApplicationLog on al2.SessionId equals al.SessionID
   select al2.Timestamp).Min())
select new
  {
    al.Message,
    al.SessionId,
    al.Timestamp
  };
```

Comment: Worked like a dream - Linqer looks like a must have, thanks for the tip Frank.